# Create 2 projects with shared code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a winforms project, which I want to change very few stuff, and compile as a different exe (for example the icon, title, and disable/enable some features).

How can I do that? I'd rather not create a second project, since I want changes to files of one, to be mirrored in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I have figured, is to create a branch with some version control system, and selectively merge classes. This way you can integrate code changes from one project to the other.

Comment: A year later ... do you find a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I guess the recommended way is to create two projects under the same solution, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.